# Why does CPU usage spikes to 90% and more after wake from suspend on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, suspend, cpu, cpu-load

On an Acer C7 Chromebook running ChrUbunutu (not CROUTON) I noticed a problem after moving to 13.04.

If I put the system to sleep and then wake it up both CPU cores spike to 90%+ usage. Soon after the fans will kick on full speed and the system will slowly start to cook. However none of the processes seem to be responsible according to the System Monitor. If I reboot the machine or shut it down the usage drops back down to the expected levels.

I did not see this issue with 12.04, I did not use 12.10 long enough to notice if it was happening.

System Specs:

- Memory: 7.7 GiB (8GB)
- CPU: Intel Celeron CPU 847
- Graphics: Intel Sandybridge Mobile
- OS type: 64-bit
- Disk: 278.9 GB

**UPDATE (2013/5/15):**

/u/ryeguy on Reddit pointed me to a link concerning acpid: http://www.cisgendered.com/?p=9 seems this issue is a little more specific to closing the lid and not sleep in general. Still I'd like to draw more attention to the issue in hopes of discovering a root cause and working towards a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem:

```
sudo stop acpid
sudo bash
echo 'manual' > /etc/init/acpid.override
```

To undo, if needed:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/acpid.override
sudo start acpid
```

Comment: your link is broken