# Ubuntu 19.04 Xorg cpu usage after sleep

Tags: gnome, xorg, 19.04, cpu-load

I recently updated to 19.04 from 18.04 with a fresh install, because it was going very slow (not sure what the reason was, possibly something I did wrong). But from day 1 on ubuntu 19.04 I noticed it was still going pretty slow in some cases. Most of the time it runs smooth until I put my pc in sleep and wake it back up, it goes very laggy. If I take a look at top, XOrg seems to be using waay to much cpu than it should. If it runs smoothly it uses 2-10% cpu, after sleep it's using 20-60% cpu. At this point its not really possible to work with it.

It doesn't matter what programs I run, even if I haven't start any program and I put it to sleep and back up it has the problem. Another strange thing is that after I wake up, my background/wallpaper on desktop and on login screen are gone and is changed to some snowy texture. Open/Close windows is insanely slow as well.

I have an nvidia 860M gpu and Intel 4710HQ cpu. I use the recommended nvidia driver by ubuntu (nvidia-driver-418) which is installed automatically.

Any idea on what I can do to fix this? I've seen some people having the same-ish problem as me, but they all report something to do with chromium, which I don't use since it was already doing this the first 10 minutes after a fresh install.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: running `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq` returns the following:

Before sleep:

```
1848445
2051080
2530366
2483812
1596207
2095278
2679695
2634235
```

After sleep:

```
927871
825019
2576392
1607589
1547249
1688311
2038285
2567913
```

Comment: What are your CPU clock frequencies before and after sleep? Do `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/293578/why-does-cpu-usage-spikes-to-90-and-more-after-wake-from-suspend-on-ubuntu-13-0

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/69120/100-cpu-usage-with-on-demand-setting-due-to-xorg

Comment: @DougSmythies I added the info to the question

Comment: all the clock frequencies please. I'm wanting to determine if they are stuck at a low value for some reason. And is your processor an i7-4710HQ or i?-4710HQ? I guess i7, because there doesn't seem to be an i5 or i3 version

Comment: I7 Indeed. And oof, sorry, it always autocompleted to cpu0 when using cpu*, so I assumed it was the wrong one. I'll add them in a minute.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be CPU frequency scaling related.

Comment: @DougSmythies I think JC97 could use the program `top` before suspending. Note the highest processes and CPU% utilization. After resuming check again and note the differences?

Comment: After suspending xorg uses between 20 and 60% like I said in the question. No one a solution?